# Preg replace - Add at and dot characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm currently a function of variables that excludes all characters except az and 0-9.
But now it does not, of course, e-mails, there need to add that it took @ and dot.

```
function POST($name) {
        $text = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9]/i", "",  $_POST[$name]);
        return $text;
    }
```

I dont know where i must add it to work, before or after.

Comment: Why are you passing a parameter `$name` and not using it?

Comment: Add `@` and `.` to your `[^...]` character class, if you don't want it to only match alphanumeric symbols anymore. Consider a more descriptive function name; or perhaps just filter_var()/FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL instead.

Comment: @Machavity ,you thing in $_POST or on function?
mario , Okey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all characters except az, 0.9, @ and dot:

```
function POST($name) {
    $text = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9@.]/i", "",  $_POST[$name]);
    return $text;
}
```

example:

```
$var = !!ci"!34!^@!!.!°aa!
```

after replace:

```
$var = ci34@.aa
```